# ChildView goes invisible

Tags: android, fragment, viewgroup

I have this piece of code here. As you can see the noItemBox is a message that is displayed when adapter is empty or null. However the problem is everytime I switch the tab and get the fragment back the noItemBox is visible. Why is this happening? can anyone please help me out on this, would appreciate it very much. Thanks.

```
if (adapter == null || (adapter != null && adapter.isEmpty())) {
        if (noItemBox == null) {
            noItemBox = new NoItemBox(getActivity());
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            int marginTop = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 5;
            params.setMargins(0, marginTop, 0, 0);
            rootView.addView(noItemBox, params);
            // check root view address
        }

        noItemBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(launchMode == Constants.LAUNCH_MODE_LOCATOR || launchMode == Constants.LAUNCH_MODE_ORDER_CART_Add) {
            noItemBox.setDesc(getString(R.string.error_msg_cant_find_location));
        } else {
            noItemBox.setTitle(getString(R.string.no_saved_rest));
            noItemBox.setImage(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dashboard_savedstores));
        }
        //  storeList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        storeList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (noItemBox != null ) {
            noItemBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you invoke this code?

Comment: Well I figured out the problem. Even tough the rootView was not being recreated noItemBox was still in memory and attached to older parentView. 

Removed view onPause using ((ViewGroup) noItemBox.getParent()).removeView(noItemBox);